# Ambiguity in picking up second harmonic generation

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electric-current, greens-functions, non-linear-optics

I want to derive some formula for second harmonic generation (SHG) susceptibility $\chi(2\omega;\omega,\omega)$. To this end, I use Matsubara Green functions to find the second-order response
$$J^a_q=\sum_{q'}\chi^{abc}_{qq'}A_{q'}^bA_{q-q'}^c \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
where $q,q'$ are Matsubara frequencies and $A_{q}^b$ is the external vector potential in direction $b$ of frequency $q$. For the real electric field, it has vector potential $A_\omega$ of frequency $\omega$.

Then we can use the analytic continuation $iq\rightarrow2\omega+i\eta$ for SHG. However, the above expression seems to be for *all possible* $\chi(\Omega;\omega,\Omega-\omega)$ since $q'$ (playing the role of $\omega$) is summed up. In order to get $\chi(2\omega;\omega,\omega)$, I presume one should additionally fix $q'$ as $q=2q'$ and drop the summation, which means analytic continuation $$iq\rightarrow2\omega+i\eta,\quad iq'\rightarrow\omega+i\eta.\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Is this the correct way at all?

When deriving such formulas, I also notice that for \eqref{eq1} with $\chi^{abc}_{qq'}$ we can make some simple shift and redefine variable $q'$ such as $q'\rightarrow q-q'$, and eventually obtain a different form $\tilde\chi^{abc}_{qq'}$ with other things in \eqref{eq1} effectively intact. This is perfectly fine for \eqref{eq1} by exploiting the unbounded summation over $q'$. However, it seems that this will change the SHG result as we drop the summation, simply because $\chi\neq\tilde\chi$ in general for particular $q,q'$.

Does it mean some contradiction or not?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do and why you use the Matsubara Green functions. The way the degeneracy in the frequency is maintained is by using phase matching conditions exploiting the birefringence of the nonlinear material. What transformations are you referring to? The susceptibility tensor obeys what are called Kleinman symmetries.

Comment: @flippiefanus There are merits of using Matsubara and I want to use green's function in the formulation. Linear response Kubo formula can also be derived this way. I'm simply using it for a second-order response. The transformation I mentioned is simply like shifting the variable e.g., $q'\rightarrow q-q'$ being summed, valid for any unbounded sum or integral. It doesn't seem to mess with Kleinman symmetry.

Comment: Perhaps you can unpack the expression for the susceptibility tensor a bit. Usually, the tensor is teated as being independent of frequency (or wave vectors), but there is a phase matching function and also the spatial mode of the illuminating beam providing wave vector dependences. It is not clear in your formulation how these are incorporated.

Comment: @flippiefanus Updated the other description a bit. The tensor is a little complicated to write down and doesn't seem relevant. But the shift and redifinition of summation variable is really straightforward, in the same spirit of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx f(x+a)$. And $f(x+a)\neq f(x)$ in general once we drop the integral.